# How to change Primary Key of entity in MagicalRecord?

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, magicalrecord

I am encountering a problem when trying to set an attribute of entity class as primary key.

As we know the default primary key of entity class is `<entity>ID` in MagicalRecord. For instance I have a userID attribute in Person entity, my question is how to set userID as primary key of Person or is it even possible?

I have tried using `relatedByAttribute` to link userID with personID but it does not work for me.

Here is a screenshot of my data model
[image]

Everytime I am trying to use `MR_importFromObject` to create/retrieve a Person entity, it crashes in `MR_executeFetchRequest`

Any one can help me out? I am using cocoa pods install latest MagicalRecord framework.

Thanks!

Comment: I can't figure out what problem you are trying to solve here. What is your goal? What does messing with primary keys have to do with your crash?

Comment: @TomHarrington I want to set userID as primary key of Person entity, what is the correct way to do it?

Comment: I still can't figure out what you're trying to do. This is not SQL, you don't normally need to set a primary key of your own because Core Data manages it internally.

Comment: @TomHarrington I am using MagicalRecord framework to manage core data, in MagicalRecord it treats ```<entity>ID``` as "primary key", now I wanna customise it to some other attribute in the entity. As of now, I am still not sure whether it is possible in MagicalRecord

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I have found why it did not work in my case.

I should set `relatedByAttribute` in Person entity to `userID`, it was previously set at userID attribute user Info